# Debugging in eclipse using large URLs

Tags: eclipse, debugging, url, jakarta-ee, tomcat6

I was debugging my application in eclipse on tomcat server by using the URL  sent from browser to server (from app logs). However after some change in application the URL formed is pretty large thus I am not able debug it anymore. (I am using GET method).

Is there any way I can make it work ?

Comment: what do you mean with "using the URL sent from browser to server"... the common way would be to make sure tomcat is running in debug mode and the connect your eclipse to the address & port tomcat is running at. Even easier is adding tomcat in eclipse and launching it in debug mode directly from there

Comment: Yes I am using tomcat from within eclipse and in debug mode from there directly ... but the application goes through different states which can be reproduced using its interaction with server(URL)